# What happens in the Form code is extraneous for the Module

Tags: vb.net

In the Form1.vb code I put a feature to display an image in the PictureBox1.
I created then a Module that has a feature instead to save the image.
So in the Windows Form I added a button that call the module.

The module is this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Salvataggio
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
Dim PictureBox1 As New PictureBox
Public idname As String

Public Sub Save()
    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("You haven't created an image yet.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = idname
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.png)|*.png|(*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.bmp)|*.bmp"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

The Form1 instead set the image in this way:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.IT_CI_F
end sub
```

The Form1 call the module so:

```
Public Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripSave.Click
    Save()
End Sub
```

Basically after I set the image in the picturebox and then I attempt to save, seems that the module doesn't know I set the image. He think the picturebox is empty.

Comment: Copy all lines between `Module Salvataggio` and `End Module`. Paste it into your `Form1`. Finally, delete the `Salvataggio` module.

Comment: Thanks... but I created the module to not repeat every time that code. I thinked the module is a solution to not repeat the code. Don't you? You mean there is no solution except to paste every time the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't belong in a module. What you should do is create a custom control derived from picture box with a `SaveAs` functionality. Something like this:

```
Public Class UIPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Public Sub SaveAs(name As String)
        If (Me.Image Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't created an image yet.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            Using dialog As New SaveFileDialog()
                With dialog
                    .FileName = name
                    .Filter = "(*.png)|*.png|(*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.bmp)|*.bmp"
                    If (.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                        Select Case IO.Path.GetExtension(.FileName).ToLower()
                            Case ".png"
                                Me.Image.Save(.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                            Case ".jpg"
                                Me.Image.Save(.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                            Case ".bmp"
                                Me.Image.Save(.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                            Case Else
                                Throw New Exception("File extension not supported")
                        End Select
                    End If
                End With
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I get an error to the Imaging word in Imaging.ImageFormat.xxx

Comment: NP! You need to import `System.Drawing` namespace or replace `Imaging` with `System.Drawing.Imaging`.

Comment: Fixed that part using System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.**
But now I get an error to Me.Image.Save

Comment: Yes exactly I fixed using: System.Drawing.Imaging - 
The issue about Me.Image.Save is maybe because I'm still using a module?

Comment: "Me" is underlined of blue color. It says it's not valid to be used in a module.

Comment: My code is a **custom control**. You cannot copy the `SaveAs` method into a module. You need to create a new `class file`. Name it `UIPictureBox` and replace the auto-generated code with my code. Rebuild your project. Open your form and the `UIPictureBox` should be available at the top of the toolbox pane.

Comment: Sir it's ok now! Really thanks for your time. How to call the class UIPictureBox if I click the button?

Comment: Drag 'n drop a new `UIPictureBox` onto the form. (Same way as you do with other controls.) Then call `Me.UIPictureBox1.SaveAs("myfilename")` in the button click event handler.

Comment: Sorry for abusing of your kindness but I did not understand. What you mean for "Drag 'n drop a new UIPictureBox onto the form". I'm confused...

Comment: @Astolth Please refer to my edit. I've appended an image to show you.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid. I had to recompile the solution to get the UIPictureBox appears. :-|
I'm having problems with the Select case now, when I save the image. I try myself to solve before disturbing you. :)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4dgxppu4b/ - I'm supposing that the problem is around the call class code: Me.UiPictureBox1.SaveAs(idname) --- I used Dim idname As String in the Public Class Form1

Comment: My bad. You'll have to add the dot `.<extension>` in the select cases. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Very kind that help out that much, Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå.

Comment: Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå if you are available for commercial proposal please leave me your skype contact privately.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create a `new` pictureBox inside the module and that's a different object from what you have in your Form. You can add a parameter to `Save` method:

```
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
Public idname As String

Public Sub Save(PictureBox1 As PictureBox)
    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("You haven't created an image yet.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = idname
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.png)|*.png|(*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.bmp)|*.bmp"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

And then pass `PictureBox` as an argument:

```
Public Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripSave.Click
    Save(PictureBox1)
End Sub
```